# Adding an additional line in the end of the 2D Linked List

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

How should one add a line at the bottom of the `2D LinkedList` in `O(1)`? I've been running loops but I have to implement it in O(1). Could smb help?

```
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
.........//I want to add one more line here <-----

LinkedList<LinkedList<T>> myList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<T>>();
public void addLastLine(){
   LinkedList<T> rowLine = new LinkedList<T>();
   this.lastRow += 1;

        myList.add(lastRow, rowLine);
        for(int col = 0; col <= origCol; col++){
            rowLine.add(col, this.element);
        }
}
```

Comment: What line you wanna add?

Comment: @DhiwaTdG, I want to add one more additional line in the end in O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Change `myList.add(lastRow, rowLine);` to  `myList.add(rowLine);`

The add() method will add to the end in O(1) time

Comment: Unless the preparation of `lastRow` (filling it with N values)  is calculated in the complexity.

Comment: A @RealSkeptic indeed! :)

Comment: OK i'll bite the bait. @RealSkeptic has a point in that the loop to fill the row is not O(1). Depending on what you need to do with `myList` you could insert the same reference to an already built rowLine. But I can't think of a real life scenario in which this would not cause trouble

Comment: @triadiktyo, yeah but what if I want to fill out the last row with the given element. Is it possible to do that in O(1)?

Comment: My answer above will add `rowLine`  to `myList` in O(1) time. Creating `rowLine` in that method will be O(n). For the whole method to be O(1) you would need to copy a rowLine reference. I do not advise that!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the index to insert at. Just use add with the new list and no index.